# A property of quotient maps

Tags: general-topology

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)) says:

> Quotient maps $q:X\to Y$ are characterized among surjective maps by the following property: if $Z$ is any topological space and $f:Y\to Z$ is any function, then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ q$ is continuous.

What does it mean that they are *characterized* among surjective maps?

Does it mean the following: suppose $q:X\to Y$ is a surjective map, and $Y$ is equipped with a topology that has the property that if $Z$ is any topological space and $f:Y\to Z$ is any function, then $f$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ q$ is continuous. Then it follows that the topology on $Y$ is the final topology with respect to $q$.

But I don't see why this should be true.

Also, my topology lecturer called the property from the Wikipedia quote above a *"universal property" of quotient spaces*. I think this terminology is not quite accurate, since it is not a universal property in the sense of category theory. Can you confirm that thought?

Comment: That statement from Wikipedia doesn't look correct to me. Instead of “surjective maps”, it should be “surjective continuous maps”.

Comment: This is true, I think. It's because the quotient topology is the finest topology making $q$ continuous. Can you show that given such $q$ and $Y$, $q$ must be continuous, and if the topology on $Y$ is a strictly coarser topology than the quotient topology, then there's a discontinuous $f$ with $f \circ q$ continuous?

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Thanks!

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos no, we don't need that assumption. The universal property forces $q$ to be continuous. See my answer.

Comment: Looks like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075869/473276) is pretty much (the first part of) your question!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen Indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a given function $q:X\to Y$ lets define the universal property to mean: for any $f:Y\to Z$ we have that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f\circ q$ is.

All we need to show is that if $q:X\to Y$ is surjective and satisfies the universal property then $q$ is a quotient map.

*Proof.* So assume that $q$ is not a quotient map. Which means that at least one of the following holds:

1. There is a subset $U\subseteq Y$ open but $q^{-1}(U)$ is not open. Or in other words $q$ is not continuous. Then we can apply our universal property to the identity $id:Y\to Y$, $id(x)=x$ which is continuous, to obtain contradiction.
2. There is a subset $U\subseteq Y$ which is not open but $q^{-1}(U)$ is. Now consider $Z=\{0,1\}$ with [the Sierpiński topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), i.e. $\{1\}$ is open but $\{0\}$ is not. Finally let $f:Y\to Z$ be given by
   $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
   1&\text{if }x\in U\\
   0&\text{otherwise}
   \end{cases}$$
   Clearly $f$ is not continuous. However $f\circ q$ is continuous. Contradicting our universal property on $q$. $\Box$

Of course there's another implication to prove here: if $q$ is a quotient map then it satisfies the universal property. Which I leave as an exercise.

Comment: (+1) Nice answer.